# What materials can we learn for Custom Architecture?

Tags: architecture

I want to build a nearly real blockchain system based on Substrate framework for an academic study.

I have scanned the tutorials and guides, but those materials are all application level content.
Where can I find the materials for custom architecture?

For example, I want runtime and consensus work parallell, do we have methods to adjust interaction of these modules? Besides, how to learn the critical interface/trait of module, such as storage, consensus and execution?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't quite get you, But in substrate the framework is very flexible and Substrate enables you to build your own blockchain system. But it removes the bottleneck of writing your own consensus algo , networking, ddatabase, txn pool and it gives you FRAME runtime framework to write custom logic for your chain.

So if you want deeper flexibility, you can change the underlying consensus and other low level architecture.  Just clone the parity/substrate repo and change whatever you want and even if you don't want to use the existing Frame framework you can change that too ( just depends on your skills level ).

So the tutorials present right now shows you how you can create your own real blockchain with custom runtime on it. You want to work on critical infrastructure no worries just read the docs carefully. And also you can check discussion on substrate repo.